# SSRS pie chart color coding

Tags: colors, reporting-services, pie-chart

I have an ssrs report where I have many pie charts with the fields pass and fail as well as up to 3 other miscellaneous fields and I wish to be able to color the pass always green and the fail always red but the other fields could be a default value. Is this even possible to do? I have seen code examples with code for custom color in pie charts but I have no clue how to do this and have not found where I would put my custom code. What im trying to do is slightly different from what all those other examples do whith only defining a few fields.

Comment: Could you post an example of your dataset please?  It should help provide an answer how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 10):

```
=Switch
(
Fields!ResultTypeDescription.Value = "Pass", "Green",
Fields!ResultTypeDescription.Value = "Fail", "Red",
Fields!ResultTypeDescription.Value = "Assigned To Machine", "Blue",
Fields!ResultTypeDescription.Value = "Not Yet Assigned", "Orange",
True , "Gray"
```

)

In order to get our dynamic coloring working,i overrode the colors from the palette.  This is how it’s done.  Right-click on the pie and select Series Properties.  Select the Fill page and click the Expression (fx) button to define the color.