# Custom colors for pie chart in RDLC

Tags: .net, wpf, colors, rdlc, pie-chart

I know that with ReportViewer, we can define a custom pallet for the pie chart color scheme, which works well for most case. I have a case in which this won't work. Let me explain :

Some of our user would like us to be able to create a pie chart in which he would define the color for each group. Something like this :

```
Group A : Red
Group B : Blue
Group C : Green
```

If we sort all group always the same way, we could make it work sometime, but suppose we have no element for Group A, then all colors would be switch by one. Plus, in this particular case, we have plenty of group and most of the do NOT appears on all pie charts.

If this is possible, we will force the user to select a color for all possible group and then the pie chart would always have the same color for the same group, no matter the number of groups visible in the pie chart.

Is this even possible and if so how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the fill colour for the series to an expression based on the data?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11654835/124386

Comment: I didn't try anything since it seemed impossible at first, but I will give it a try. My fear is that since I have more than one pie chart (one per grouping), that I won't be able to change the 'palette' for earh of them